# Does the android dalvik vm use escape analysis optimization?

Tags: android, dalvik, escape-analysis

Any ideas about escape analysis in dalvik? Or when and if it's planned to be added?

I consider escape analysis a very important feature in GC languages to avoid churning out objects every time a method is called, and currently I preallocate an object in the class and reset it at the beginning of the method, so I avoid allocation (I am writing 3D games for android...in java), but I find this method ugly and keeps the memory hogged with preallocated objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any ideas about escape analysis in dalvik?

There is [source code in the `dx` portion of the Dalvik project](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/dx/src/com/android/dx/ssa/EscapeAnalysis.java) that performs some limited escape analysis. Whether this is actually used in production, I cannot say, and the topic certainly does not seem to come up very much.

> Or when and if it's planned to be added?

Google does not make much in the way of forward-thinking statements regarding Android's capabilities.

Comment: I believe the code you cite didn't end up getting activated, mainly because it didn't seem to help significantly in practice, and IIRC it could confuse debuggers.

Comment: @danfuzz: Thanks for the info! It's great to get expert info on these sorts of details.